# Why does the memory will be increased (t4 template)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, t4

the memory will be increased (1M-3M) when i call this method :engine.ProcessTemplate(inputTemplate, host).I don't know why?

Note:i use t4 template to generate code.

this is my code:

```
Engine engine = new Engine();
host.Session = new TextTemplatingSession();
 Parameter nameSpaceParameter = new Parameter() { Text = "NameSpace", Value = this.txtNameSpaceRoot.Text };//+ strTmp.Replace("Templates." + this.CurSelectedNode.DisplayName, string.Empty)
host.Session.Add("NameSpace", nameSpaceParameter);

Parameter tableNameParameter = new Parameter() { Text = "TableName", Value = oName.Substring(2)};
host.Session.Add("TableName", tableNameParameter);
string inputTemplate = File.ReadAllText(host.TemplateFileValue);
string content=engine.ProcessTemplate(inputTemplate, host);
```

this is my t4 template file :

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ parameter name="NameSpace" type="SmartCodeGenerator.Parameter" #>
<#@ parameter name="TableName" type="SmartCodeGenerator.Parameter" #>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using <#=NameSpace.Value#>.DAL;
using <#=NameSpace.Value#>.Model;
namespace <#=NameSpace.Value#>.BLL
{
    public class <#=TableName.Value#>Repository 
    {
        RepositoryBase<<#=TableName.Value#>Model> repository = null;
        public <#=TableName.Value#>Repository()
        {
            repository = new RepositoryBase<<#=TableName.Value#>Model>();

        }
        #region IRepository<T> 成员

        public <#=TableName.Value#>Model Create()
        {
            return repository.Create();
        }

        public <#=TableName.Value#>Model Update(<#=TableName.Value#>Model entity)
        {
            return repository.Update(entity);
        }

        public <#=TableName.Value#>Model Insert(<#=TableName.Value#>Model entity)
        {
            return repository.Insert(entity);
        }

        public void Delete(<#=TableName.Value#>Model entity)
        {
            repository.Delete(entity);
        }

        public IList<<#=TableName.Value#>Model> FindAll()
        {
            return repository.FindAll();

        }
        public List<<#=TableName.Value#>Model> QueryByPage<TKey>(Expression<Func<<#=TableName.Value#>Model, bool>> filter, Expression<Func<<#=TableName.Value#>Model, TKey>> orderby, int OrderType, int Take, int Skip, out int recordsCount)
        {
            recordsCount = repository.Query(filter).Count();
            if (OrderType == 0)
            {
                return repository.Query(filter).OrderBy(orderby).Take(Take).Skip(Skip).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return repository.Query(filter).OrderByDescending(orderby).Take(Take).Skip(Skip).ToList();
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but does an increase of 3MB in memory consumption really matter? Can you explain your case further?

Comment: I agree with @IlianPinzon, 3MB is NOTHING! My Raspberry Pi got 80 blocks of them even.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's causing your concern here, or what scenario is causing you to need to instantiate the engine directly as opposed to using the VS Service interface. However, if the instantiation of the Engine is the first time you call any T4 method in a given VS process, then the NGEN'd assemblies will be faulted in, causing a working set jump. If its on the call to ProcessTemplate, then this may be the first use your actual Parameter assembly in your scenario.  It's a bit hard to tell without more context.